# select only newest date from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select and display only the newest records entered in my DB. for example I have the following table: having 4 columns **company**, **item**, **price** and **Date**. What i need to do is that select all the columns and display as they are if there is no other price add to the table. If new item price added to the table always the news record should show up. I tried several codes but didn't work for me. so i appreciate if any one can help me with this.

```
price
=====
company      Item       Price   Date
ABC          Item1     100    1-07-2015
DEF          Item1     200    1-06-2015
GHI          Item1     400    1-07-2014
JKL          Item1     110    1-07-2015
```

Thanks!

Comment: i really hope that's not he date stored in the db, as mysql uses YYYY-MM-DD format. as to the rest of the question im really quite confused

Comment: @Dagon And the mysql format would make answering this question a whole lot easier...

Comment: @kittykittybangbang sure would, not that im really sure what it is :-)

Comment: OP is just asking to order the result by latest date

Comment: yet mentions adding to the table as well ?

Comment: @Dagon that he referes for future records so incase there is more records added always order by latest date

Comment: yeah i'll leave ya to it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbdcc/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE price
    (`company` varchar(3), `Item` varchar(5), `Price` int, `Date` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO price
    (`company`, `Item`, `Price`, `Date`)
VALUES
    ('ABC', 'Item1', 100, '2015-07-01 00:00:00'),
    ('DEF', 'Item1', 200, '2015-07-01 00:00:00'),
    ('GHI', 'Item1', 400, '2014-07-01 00:00:00'),
    ('JKL', 'Item1', 110, '2015-07-01 00:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
        p.*
from price p
inner join (
  select `Item`, MAX(`Date`) as MaxDate
  from price
  group by `Item`
  ) m on p.`Item` = m.`Item` and p.`Date` = m.MaxDate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbdcc/4/0)**:

```
| company |  Item | Price |                   Date |
|---------|-------|-------|------------------------|
|     ABC | Item1 |   100 | July, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|     DEF | Item1 |   200 | July, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
|     JKL | Item1 |   110 | July, 01 2015 00:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
SELECT MAX(Date) FROM price //in case of timestamp
```

or use below if you want to fetch only single record

```
SELECT Date FROM price ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM price ORDER BY Date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select * from (your_database_name) Order by Date DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

how about using trigger.

very simple insert trigger will help  you.

[mysql trigger exmple](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

i guess what you want is getting the new inserted datas after checking the data at some time.

so you must know the last record's id you checked.

session or cookie is not a good answer.

so  you need to make a table which contains last record id which you checked.

```
select * from table where id > (select id from another_table);
```

when you check the record

```
update another_table set id = (select max(id) from table);
```